# What's meant here by "funked it" and "bolted off"?

Tags: meaning

In "The Man with Two Beards" by G. K. Chesterton, the author was describing a situation where Mr. Bankes family were assembling in their house while their son, John, returned in his car with his neighbour, Mr. Smith, who don't like cars at all:

> At this point, the conference was for a moment disturbed, by the return of John Bankes, from what appeared to be an abortive expedition in the car. Old Smith seemed to have been a disappointing passenger, after all. "**Funked it**, after all, at the last minute," he announced with noisy disgust. "**Bolted off while I was looking at what I thought was a puncture**. Last time I’ll take one of these yokels——"

Does "**funked it**" mean "**got rid of it**"?

And what's meant by "Bolted off, does it mean "escaped" as "bolted out"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Funk* is rather old-fashioned British slang for a state of fear, so to *funk it* is to lose one's nerve at the last moment and refuse to do something. We might say *chicken out* today.

To *bolt* is to run away, like a frightened horse. It doesn't need *off* after it, but I suppose John is using it like *ran off.*